# How to change column type with migration with GRDB Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, grdb

I have a couple of tables with `UUID` as the type of their columns.

I want to convert those columns to `String` rather than `UUID` as debugging is just pain in the arse (e.g. browsing the **sqlite** file using **DB Browser for SQLite** requires me to do SQL query just to convert the `UUID` objects to `String`s to see the id values.

Going back to the question, what's the most practical way to do this?

I am thinking, and about to do, but I want to ask this first:

1. in the `registerMigration`, create a new table.
2. new table has the String columns now.
3. loop through the rows o the old table, and move those rows to the new table BUT making sure that the ids are now in `String`s and not `UUID`s.
4. drop old table
5. rename new table to the old table's name.

```
registerMigration("UUIDMigrationToString") { db in
      try db.create(table: "new_table") { table in
        table.autoIncrementedPrimaryKey("id")
        table.column("someIdStuff", .text).notNull()
      }

      // loop through the old table...
      // move the rows from the old table to the new table but with string Ids.
      // drop old table, and rename new table.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered by GRDB author here: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/issues/1077

But here's my solution based on that answer, should be pretty straightforward:

```
import GRDB

extension DatabaseMigrator {
  /**
   Migrate UUIDs to String
   
   References:
   
   - https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/issues/1077
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69598215/how-to-change-column-type-with-migration-with-grdb-swift
   */
  mutating func v1_8() {
    migrateStream()
  }
  
  // MARK: - Stream
  
  mutating func migrateStream() {
    registerMigration("1.8 - Stream") { db in
      
      try db.create(table: "new_stream") { table in
        table.autoIncrementedPrimaryKey("id")
        table.column("contentId", .text).notNull()
        table.column("streamId", .text).notNull()
      }
      
      let rows = try Row.fetchCursor(db, sql: "SELECT * FROM stream")
      while let row = try rows.next() {
        try db.execute(
          sql: "INSERT INTO new_stream (id, contentId, streamId) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
          arguments: [
            row["id"],
            (row["contentId"] as UUID).uuidString,
            (row["streamId"] as UUID).uuidString
          ])
      }
      
      try db.drop(table: "stream")
      try db.rename(table: "new_stream", to: "stream")
    }
  }
```